# How to uninstall PAEAFLT.sys drivers that do not belong to any device but that is forbidding from enabling Memory Integrity in Core Isolation?

Tags: windows, memory, windows-11, core

`Core isolation`, `Memory integrity`, `What if it says I have an incompatible driver?`:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/core-isolation-e30ed737-17d8-42f3-a2a9-87521df09b78

As you can see, the folders where these files are are these:

[image]

In device manager, even using the option to show hidden devices, no device listed there has these names or belonging to the values that I will show below.

I don't have any Philips or PixArt Imaging Incorporation programs on my computer, but these drivers appear to prohibit enabling Memory Integrity in the Core Isolation security functions:

[image]

No device has this data either.

How should I uninstall these drivers? Deleting directly in the folder?

Comment: You can use *pnputil /enum-drivers* to enumerate through all drivers then use the same utility to delete the driver once you identify the .inf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I uninstall these drivers? Deleting directly in the folder?

You can use `pnputil /enum-drivers` to enumerate through all your device drivers to confirm that oem52.inf is the correct file connected to the .sys file in question.  Once you have identified that is indeed the case you can use `pnputil /delete-driver oem52.inf` to get rid of the file.

*It's important to highlight the number of the oemxx.inf file might be different on another system.*

Comment: How to confirm if an ".inf" is connected to a certain ".sys" file?

Comment: @Egret - The output of the enumeration of the drivers would provide that information. Core Isolation also makes that known.  It's also contained within the .inf file but this answer shouldn't be used to do anything except fix Core Isolation as it does contain the information to do anything else.

Comment: The output seems to only show the corresponding "oemXX.inf" with another .inf name, not .sys

Comment: @Egret - Sounds like you have a unique question. I can’t answer your question as a comment. The inf file itself also indicates the driver file and the device. Unless you have feedback for me I won’t receive any additional notifications of comments to this answer.