# How can I get rid of a specific driver that I'm not even using?

Tags: drivers, windows-11, webcam

I am unable to turn on Memory Integrity in Windows due to an incompatible Logitech driver.  I no longer even own a Logitech webcam, and this driver has not been updated since 2012 (hence the warning).

lvbflt64.sys

I checked in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers and the file is not there.

I checked Device Manager and the web cam isn't even listed (even when Show Hidden is on).

I do not have any Logitech control panel type software on my machine.

How can I find and remove this driver so that I can turn Memory Integrity back on?  Getting highly technical doesn't scare me off, I just want it gone.

[image: Incompatible Logitech Driver]

When I search on disk, I see these in the DriverStore.  I have tried every trick I can think of to remove these, I can't.  They require SYSTEM level permissions to remove manually.

[image: Files on Disk]

The reason I'm going through all of this pain is to get rid of the insecure flag that Defender shows in the taskbar.  I fully understand what Core Isolation is/does, I am a software engineer.

I just want a clean system and I don't want Logitech drivers from 2012 on my machine when I don't even use Logitech devices.   And these drivers are now interfering with system security.

[image: Defender Flag]

Comment: what do you get from starting cmd as administrator and running `cd \ ` + enter + `dir *lvbflt64* /s /b`  ?  (the last command might take a while, especially if you're not on a SSD)

Comment: @hanshenrik Returns two results within `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\`

Comment: Memory integrity is a work in progress that does not work on any of my Windows 11 machines brand new, or older.  I do not have any driver incompatibilities on new machines. This is a Microsoft bug and a deeply flawed idea.

Comment: (1) Check if in the Device Manager you have any Logitech devices and delete them, reboot, and try again. If error, check if the device hasn't returned. (2) If you have any drivers named `lv*.sys`, rename or move them elsewhere, reboot, and try again.

Comment: @harrymc Device Manager is clean as I noted, even with Show Hidden.  The files are in the Windows DriverStore and I can't remove them (see updated image in post).

Comment: Do not change permissions on Windows folders, since undoing is not always possible. Boot a Linux Live USB to do the rename or move.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer) for OneNote printer.  The principal is the same.

Comment: Which model name had your camera? Did you search the logitech driver support page for a driver uninstall tool?

Comment: The way to uninstall drivers is either using the device manager GUI (sometimes with the DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1 flag) or using the pnputil command.  If you need to do more than that, back up your stuff completely and get hacking.  If you can't figure out how to get to this from the answer I point to above.. I can help you.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I did a system restore point, and then ran pnputil.exe /remove-device oem109.inf, the offending file as shown in the screenshot.   Nothing.  I've also tried GUI utilities like DevManView, and even tried Disk Cleanup to remove old driver backups.  Nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall PAEAFLT.sys drivers that do not belong to any device but that is forbidding from enabling Memory Integrity in Core Isolation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1736044/how-to-uninstall-paeaflt-sys-drivers-that-do-not-belong-to-any-device-but-that-i)

Comment: Once you remove the .inf file your issue should be solved (as documented by the duplicate), `pnputil.exe /remove-device oem109.inf`, is the incorrect command.  I have used the method I documented in my answer to solve a similar problem.  However, it wasn't a Logitech driver, so if it keeps coming back it's likely an I/O device. You made no mention of the results of pnputil.exe, which should be in your question body, but I stand by a duplicate vote regardless due to the syntax error.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the command I issued, the folder remains with the driver, and the inf, and Windows is picking this up as offending.  Is this driver even loaded??  I'm not running anthing Logitech.  Why does it have driver backups for something that doesn't exist?  Even Disk Cleanup, which removes old driver copies, should handle this.

Comment: You ran *pnputil.exe /remove-device oem109.inf* or *pnputil /delete-driver oem109.inf* Can you open the inf file and tell us what device it’s for?

Comment: @Ramhound The output it nothing.  It jut says "Microsoft PnP Utility" after I run it.  The folder and the offending driver, and inf, remain in DriverStore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139784/discussion-between-ramhound-and-patrick).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the device manager:

- Select `View` → `Devices by driver`
- Right click on the driver (in your case `oem109.inf`)
- Enable both tick boxes:

  - <kbd>✓</kbd> Uninstall this driver from any device that currently use it.
  - <kbd>✓</kbd> Attempt to force remove of this driver while it is still in use by the devices

(reboot the system)

Comment: This worked ... learn something new every day!   Thanks.

Comment: This is the unique solution found on entire internet that solves! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Procedure above is good. Additionally, after step 2 (right-click), select "Properties" and then click the "Remove Driver" box. After that, the two tick boxes are presented.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1166749)