# How to get rid of some drivers that won't let me enable Core Isolation>Memory Integrity in Windows 11?

Tags: drivers, security, windows-11

So I am trying to turn on the security feature called `Memory integrity` inside `Core Isolation` in my machine, running Windows 11.

It won't let me because I have a list of probably outdated drivers, problem is, I don't know how to uninstall them and if I actually need them. They are all from either Huawei or ZTE, brands with which I have no relation (I don't own any device from them neither), so I don't even know how those drivers ended up there.

Is there any way to make sure that I don't need them and uninstall them so I can enable the feature?

---

Here is the list of the drivers, as provided by Windows in the same tab:

- `ewusbmdm.sys` -> `oem42.inf`
- `ew_usbenumfilter.sys` -> `oem44.inf`
- `ew_hwusbdev.sys` -> `oem45.inf`
- `ZTEusbgser.sys` -> `oem52.inf`
- `ZTEusbser6k` -> `oem55.inf`
- `ZTEusbnmea.sys` -> `oem58.inf`
- `ZTEusbnmeaext.sys` -> `oem59.inf`
- `ZTEusbnmeaext2.sys` -> `oem60.inf`
- `ZTEusbvoice.sys` -> `oem61.inf`
- `ewusbmdm.sys` -> `oem40.inf`
- `zteusbgser.sys` -> `oem51.inf`
- `ZTEusbmdm6k.sys` -> `oem56.inf`
- `ew_hwusbdev.sys` -> ??
- `ew_usbenumfilter.sys` -> ??

Comment: Personally, I'd just uninstall them. Nothing from either of those chinee spy brands is likely to be required on your computer - and the fact that they are blocking a security feature should be ringing major alarm bells (not in Beijing until you uninstall of course )

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer but here is an article on how to do it. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-turn-on-memory-integrity-and-core-isolation-in-windows-10 . The method using pnputil  is the one you need. I'm assuming it still works for Windows 11.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some additional information.  Windows should be indicating which driver (`.sys`) and the name of the `.inf` file responsible, without this information, a helpful detailed answer is impossible to write.  You can get a start by using [`pnputil /enum-drivers`](https://superuser.com/questions/1736044/how-to-uninstall-paeaflt-sys-drivers-that-do-not-belong-to-any-device-but-that-i/1736151#1736151)

Comment: @DavidMarshall really helpful indeed. Would you find the time to write an answer I'll accept it. I will also list the drivers but I honestly don't think I need them.